# Testcontainers mongodb - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Tags: spring, mongodb, docker, docker-for-windows, testcontainers

I have basic `Spring` repository:

```
@Repository
public interface LRepository extends MongoRepository<L, String> {}
```

And I am using it inside a service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class SerImpl {
    private final LRepository repository;

    public String saveL(L l) {
        l = repository.save(l);
        return l.id;
    }
}
```

On line with `.save(l)` my test timeouts.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {MongoIntegrationTest.TestPropertiesInitializer.class})
class MongoIntegrationTest {
    private SerImpl serImpl;

    @Autowired
    private LRepository lRepository;

    public static class TestPropertiesInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            final TestPropertyValues values = TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost",
                    "spring.data.mongodb.username=root",
                    "spring.data.mongodb.password=example",
                    "spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin",
                    "spring.data.mongodb.database=l",
                    "spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017"
            );
            values.applyTo(configurableApplicationContext);
        }
    }

    @Container
    public GenericContainer mongoDb = new GenericContainer("mongo:4.2.2")
            .withExposedPorts(27017)
            .withEnv("MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME", "root")
            .withEnv("MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD", "example");

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mongoDb.start();

        String address = mongoDb.getContainerIpAddress();
        //List<Integer> exposedPorts = mongoDb.getExposedPorts();
        Integer port = mongoDb.getFirstMappedPort();
        Map<String,String> map = mongoDb.getEnvMap();
        serImpl = new SerImpl(lRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSimplePutAndGet() {
        String id = serImpl.saveL(new L("aaa"));
        assertNotNull(id);
    }
}
```

On line `l = repository.save(l);`

I get an error saying

> ```
> org.mongodb.driver.cluster     : Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out.
> ```

I tried to fix it by increasing timeout:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        return MongoClientOptions
                .builder()
                .serverSelectionTimeout(180000)
                .build();
    }
}
```

But more time did not help me here.
`L` is object with `String` field.
I simplified code above to make it more **M**VCE.
When the test runs i see the container running and exposing the port.

If i start mongo container from docker the test is successful.

I am running it on Windows.

Comment: It seems your MongoDb binds inside docker with such bind_ip 127.0.0.1, so inside docker you can access mongo. Try yo change: 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Valijon Sorry, i did not undesrtand you. The container currently starts as `0.0.0.0:32791->27017/tcp`. Could you be more specific what you want me to change?

Answer (score 2):

I've added:

```
    mongoDb.setPortBindings(List.of("27017:27017"));
```

This Fix this issue:

> org.mongodb.driver.cluster     : Cluster description not yet
>   available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out.

Comment: Where did you add this ?